# Sending files to CentOS machine via ssh

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, centos, putty

I'm using ssh and connecting to a linux machine for the first time from my Windows 7 machine and right now I'm using putty to access a CentOS machine via ssh.

I need to transfer some big files to the CentOS machine but I don't know how to do it, I searched around but couldn't understand how to do it in a simple way.

Can someone please explain me simply how to do it?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [winscp](http://www.winscp.net). It is an scp (secure copy for Linux) client for Windows. scp uses ssh to communicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use SCP.

I use [WINSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use PSCP from the PuTTY folks.